# I can't log out in website developing with wordpress and facebook connect

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I was using facebook connect in my website(CMS-Wordpress). The problem what I'm facing is user can't logout after logged in. It drives me crazy. Anybody got that problem and how fixed it? Let me share your experience.

Comment: Added, log out effected in facebook. But, not my website.

Comment: I'm using wp-facebookconnect plug-in. Sorry for my reply late.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to send a logout request to Facebook connect?